# DOM animation for elements moved because of adding another Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, dom, element

my question depends on the following scenario:

I have an JS script, which adds a span element into a div. As the div has a text-align:middle;, the already existing spans are "jumping" to the left or right as soon as the new span gets appended or removed.

is there any way how to animate the jumps of the elements, without calculating it manually in the code for each span element in the container div every time an elements gets added?

you can see my problem here: http://dev.choozi.de/slide/tags.php, as you click on a tag, the others are jumping in the upper blue box.

To make it more clear, the other elements, which are moving because I'm adding a new element, should slide to the left or roight to make enough space for the new element, not jumping.

I would like to have something like this for CSS transitions, but for all DOM transitions.

```
* {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Is there a project which does this or an easy way to handle that problem via jQuery or JS?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Here's a stab at animating with JQuery: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nqz4bL3/). I tried doing something similar with CSS transitions, but I'm just not that familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

Well based on @John S's answer I made up some code, wich is working pretty well:

**HTML**

```
<div class="choosen_tags_holder"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.choosen_tags_holder span {
    padding: 0 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**JS**

```
/* ===== REMOVES THE CLICKED ELEMENT FROM THE CONTAINER ===== */
function removeFromTagContainer(liElement) {
    $('.choosen_tags_holder span').each(function (e) {
        if ($(this).html() === liElement.next().html()) {
            $(this).animate({ width: 0 }, '500');
            $(this).animate({ padding: 0 }, '100');
            removeContent($(this));
        }
    }); 
}

/* ===== ADDS THE CLICKED ELEMENT TO THE CONTAINER ===== */
function addToTagContainer(liElement) {
    var $span = $('<span>'+liElement.next().html()+'</span>').hide().prependTo(choosenTagsContainer);
    var width = $span.width();
    $span.css({ width: 0 }).show().animate({ width: width }, '500');
}
```

How it looks when it is working? Here: http://dev.choozi.de/slide/tags.php

IT's not a general solution like the CSS code from my question, but it is indeed working for most problems of adding and animating DOM elements.

So thank you very much for your help!